# Retrieve ZODB database structure

Tags: python, database, zodb

I recently received a ZODB file (.fs) which contain a [erp5](http://www.erp5.org/) database. I need to retrieve the data stored but I don't know the database structure.

What I need is some lines of code (if possible) to gather the "tables" and the "records" stored in the DB.

This is how I get connected to the database.

```
from ZODB import FileStorage, DB

storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('D:\slappart88\srv\zodb\main.fs')

db = DB(storage)
conn = db.open()
root = conn.root()
fsi = storage.iterator()

print db
print conn
print root
print fsi

db.close()
```

Getting this output:

```
<ZODB.DB.DB object at 0x00000000028395C0>
<Connection at 02978128>
{'Application': <persistent broken OFS.Application.Application instance     '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'>}
<ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage.FileIterator object at 0x0000000002978198>
```

I'll appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found any solution forma this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

ZODB is an "object" storage file format.  It doesn't really have "records" and "tables"; it *does* have a collection of [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) objects, and it's really meant to be used by the particular application that knows about those objects.

If your primary goal is just inspecting the contents of the ZODB, you can try [eye](https://github.com/davisagli/eye), which gives you a browser-based interface to the database contents.

Looking at the code for `eye` may offer some ideas on how to extract information yourself, although there's an excellent chance you won't be able to get anything useful without using the originating application.

There's a longer discussion of this topic [here](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/45764-how-export-data-zodb-text-files).

Comment: Thank you @larsks ! I tried _eye_ and it was kinda what I was looking for. But as you said, I've got nothing really useful. I think I need to dive into the ERP5 code. I need to export the data to a readable, human friendly format.

Comment: I've fixed the link.